# How to change grid default status in a ZK theme?

Tags: zk, zk-grid

I have a page built with ZK. In this page there is a button that start a search. If there are some data them appear in a grid view.
Every data are built in this way:
v Date1 (dd/mm/yyyy)
   - item
   - item
   - item
v Date2 (dd/mm/yyyy)
   - item
   - item

Lecter V means an arrow but I can't post an image so I use a "v" that have similar image to undestand.

It works correctely but there is a problem.
I would have this situation:

> Date1 (dd/mm/yyyy)
>
> Date2 (dd/mm/yyyy)

When I click on a date I want that the arrow became "v" and all data appear.
If in the first case I click on date it became close.

How to change the default view of grid items?

This is my code

```
<grid id="demoGrid" width="50%" height="400px" style ="float:left"
        model="@bind(vm.value)" emptyMessage="No data">
        <columns menupopup="auto">
            <column sort="auto(Hour)" label="Hour" width="150px"/>
            <column sort="auto(Value)" label="Value(bpm)" hflex="1" />             
        </columns>
        <!-- template for group -->
        <template name="model:group">
            <group label="@load(each)" />
        </template>

        <!-- template for each element in model -->
        <template name="model" >

            <row>
                <label value="@load(each.hour)" />
                <label value="@load(each.value)" />                
            </row>
        </template>

        <!-- template for footer -->
        <template name="model:groupfoot">
            <groupfoot>
                <cell colspan="5" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px">
                    <label value="@load(each)" style="font-weight:bold;" />
                </cell>
            </groupfoot>
        </template>

    </grid>
```

I try to use tag details in this subcode:

```
<template name="model">
    <details open="false">
        <row>
            <label value="@load(each.hour)" />
            <label value="@load(each.value)" />                
        </row>
    </details>
</template>
```

Comment: do you use ZK EE? details is only in ZK EE

Comment: Yes I have ZK EE, but details in this way doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the details like this :

```
<template name="model">
    <row>
        <detail open="false">
            <hlayout>
                <label value="@load(each.hour)" />
                <label value="@load(each.value)" />                
            </hlayout>
        </detail>
        <label value="second column"/>
    </row>
</template>
```

Explication :

- Detail can have only **1 root element** so that's why we set the the `hlayout`.
  Of course you can change this to div or whatever you want.
- The `row` tag has to be outside the detail tag.
- The `detail` take a column so for this example you need to provide 2 columns.

### Edit :

[I created a fiddle.](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/br3a5g/1-simple-mvvm-detail-example)

Comment: This does not work! However I need that a group of data be default hidden! Now when I opened the page, I saw the list opened! I want that the list are closed!

Comment: I have a list of exceptions about the not right position of tag details

Comment: Now I change (because the tag is detail without S) and I saw it: org.zkoss.zul.Detail cannot be cast to org.zkoss.zul.Row

Comment: about the detail without s you are correct, zk version?

Comment: How can I see my version?

Comment: in the dependencies, example : ZK-7.0.1.jar

Comment: I have 7.0.0. Do I have to change?

Comment: It isn't what that I need. This not work so well. But also if it work it isn't what I need because I want that the top label is closed. Not the single row. I want that the group of rows are all default hidden. Are you understand? It's difficult to explain

Comment: I have written mail! I put 2 files as attachment